# assignment to entry in nil map

Tags: dictionary, go, instantiation

I am trying to assign values to a map that is initialized in the init func.

But panic occurs:
assignment to entry in nil map

```
package main

type Object interface { 
}

type ObjectImpl struct {
}

type Test struct{
    collection map[uint64] Object
}

func (test Test) init(){
    test.collection = make(map[uint64] Object)
}

func main() {
    test := &Test{}
    test.init()
    test.collection[1]=&ObjectImpl{}
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/yOwXzDkWIo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function takes `Test` as value, so it gets its own copy of it. All changes to `test Test` will be gone when the function returns. Take `Test` by pointer instead:

```
func (test *Test) init(){
    test.collection = make(map[uint64] Object)
}
```

Note though, the struct `Test` is exported, the method `init` is not, therefore a user of your library could potentially create a `Test` but not init it properly. It seems like the go community has established the convention of a freestanding `NewType` method:

```
type test struct{
    collection map[uint64] Object
}

function NewTest() *test {
    return &test{
        collection: make(map[uint64] Object),
    }
}
```

This ensures a user can only obtain a `test` by calling `NewTest` and it will be initialized as intended.

Comment: Makes total sense, i can't believe I didnt realize this myself. Thanks for the answer and the extra pair of eyes.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a pointer receiver for the `init` method:

```
func (test *Test) init() {  // use a pointer to test
    test.collection = make(map[uint64] Object)
}
```

Without a pointer, you are initializing a map for a copy of the `test` object. The actual `test` object never gets an initialized map.

[Working Code](https://play.golang.org/p/hqtz2mCyqR)